# Changing Separator in "Copy Names with Path to Clipboard" in Total Commander

Tags: clipboard, total-commander

In Total Commander under the `Mark` menu there are 2 menu entries:

- Copy Selected Names to Clipboard
- Copy Names with Path to Clipboard

[image: menu screenshot]

When used, the file names are copied to the clipboard with a separating new-line.

Is there a way to customize the separator between the file names?
For example, to use a `<space>` between the copied file names?

Comment: you could do a RegEx replace from "\n" to " " in your favorite text editor (https://notepad-plus-plus.org/ supports replace "In selection": http://stackoverflow.com/a/5110685/1498405)

Comment: @hardmooth: That's what I usually do...